# ModelView con varios modelos entre ellos una lista de modelos para crear mediante una vista en Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Tengo la clase `Pedidos`

```
public partial class Pedidos
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Order")]
    public string Pedido { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public int Usuario { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    public string Cliente { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Min pickup date")]
    public DateTime PickupMinDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Max pickup date ")]
    public DateTime PickupMaxDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Min delivery date ")]
    public DateTime DeliveryMinDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Max delivery date ")]
    public DateTime DeliveryMaxDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Pickup direction")]
    public string PickupDireccion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pickup second direction")]
    public string PickupDireccion2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pickup town")]
    public string PickupPoblacion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pickup postal code")]
    public string PickupCP { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pickup Country")]
    public string PickupPais { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Pickup name")]
    public string PickupNombre { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Pickup phone")]
    public string PickupTelefono { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Delivery direction")]
    public string DeliveryDireccion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delivery second direction")]
    public string DeliveryDireccion2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delivery town")]
    public string DeliveryPoblacion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delivery postal code")]
    public string DeliveryCP { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delivery Country")]
    public string DeliveryPais { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Delivery name")]
    public string DeliveryNombre { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Delivery phone")]
    public string DeliveryTelefono { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Observations")]
    public string Observaciones { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Claimer name")]
    public string NombrePeti { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Claimer email")]
    public string EmailPeti { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Claimer phone")]
    public int TelefonoPeti { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Accepted")]
    public bool Aceptado { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cancelled")]
    public bool Cancelado { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Accepted date")]
    public DateTime? FechaAceptado { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cancelled date")]
    public DateTime? FechaCancelado { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaModificacion { get; set; }

    public ICollection<LinPedidos> Lineas { get; set; }
}
```

Y la clase `LinPedidos`

```
public partial class LinPedidos
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Pedidos Pedido { get; set; }
    public int? Numero { get; set; }
    public double? Peso { get; set; }
    public int? Longitud { get; set; }
    public int? Ancho { get; set; }
    public int? Alto { get; set; }
    public string Stackable { get; set; }
}
```

Ademas con el modelBuilder les hago la relacion:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<LinPedidos>()
            .HasOne(l => l.Pedido)
            .WithMany(p => p.Lineas);
```

De tal manera que en `LinPedidos` tengo el `PedidoId` como FK de `Pedidos`

Tengo creada una vista donde quiero crear tanto `Pedido` como una lista dinamica de `LinPedidos` donde uso el modelo `Peticion`:

```
public class Peticion
{

    public Pedidos pedido { get; set; }
    public List<LinPedidos> lineas { get; set; }
}
```

Y la vista es:

```
@model project.Models.Peticion

<h1>New Order</h1>

<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Prefix</label>
                    <ejs-combobox id="prefijo" dataSource="@ViewBag.dataPrefix" index="0" placeholder="Select a prefix">
                    </ejs-combobox>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Usuario" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Usuario" class="form-control" value="@User.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value" disabled />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Usuario" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Cliente" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Cliente" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Cliente" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="PickupMinDate" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="PickupMinDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="PickupMinDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="PickupMaxDate" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="PickupMaxDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="PickupMaxDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DeliveryMinDate" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DeliveryMinDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryMinDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DeliveryMaxDate" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DeliveryMaxDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryMaxDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="PickupDireccion" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="PickupDireccion" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="PickupDireccion" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="PickupNombre" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="PickupNombre" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="PickupNombre" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="PickupTelefono" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="PickupTelefono" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="PickupTelefono" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DeliveryDireccion" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DeliveryDireccion" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryDireccion" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DeliveryNombre" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DeliveryNombre" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryNombre" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DeliveryTelefono" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DeliveryTelefono" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryTelefono" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="NombrePeti" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="NombrePeti" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="NombrePeti" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="EmailPeti" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="EmailPeti" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="EmailPeti" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="TelefonoPeti" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="TelefonoPeti" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="TelefonoPeti" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Observaciones" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Observaciones" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Observaciones" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <script>
            jQuery(document).delegate('a.add-record', 'click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var content = jQuery('#sample_table tr'),
                    size = jQuery('#tbl_lineas >tbody >tr').length + 1,
                    element = null,
                    element = content.clone();
                element.attr('id', 'rec-' + size);
                element.find('.delete-record').attr('data-id', size);
                element.appendTo('#tbl_lineas_body');
                element.find('.sn').html(size);
            });


            jQuery(document).delegate('a.delete-record', 'click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var didConfirm = confirm("Are you sure You want to delete");
                if (didConfirm == true) {
                    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
                    var targetDiv = $(this).attr('targetDiv');
                    jQuery('#rec-' + id).remove();

                    //regnerate index number on table
                    jQuery('#tbl_lineas_body tr').each(function (index) {
                        //alert(index);
                        jQuery(this).find('span.sn').html(index + 1);
                    });
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });


        </script>
        <div class="well clearfix">
            <h4 style="display:inline-block">Packages</h4>
            <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-record" data-added="0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Row</a>
        </div>

        
        <div style="display:none;">
            <table id="sample_table">
                <tr id="">
                    <td><span class="sn">1</span>.</td>
                    <td><ejs-numerictextbox id="numbers" value="1" showSpinButton="false" min="1" max="999"></ejs-numerictextbox></td>
                    <td><ejs-numerictextbox id="gross" value="100" showSpinButton="false" min="1" max="9999"></ejs-numerictextbox></td>
                    <td><ejs-numerictextbox id="lenght" value="100" showSpinButton="false" min="1" max="999"></ejs-numerictextbox></td>
                    <td><ejs-numerictextbox id="weight" value="100" showSpinButton="false" min="1" max="999"></ejs-numerictextbox></td>
                    <td><ejs-numerictextbox id="height" value="100" showSpinButton="false" min="1" max="999"></ejs-numerictextbox></td>
                    <td><ejs-textbox id="stackable"></ejs-textbox></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tbl_lineas" asp-for="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Gross weight</th>
                    <th>Length</th>
                    <th>Width</th>
                    <th>height</th>
                    <th>Stackable</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbl_lineas_body">
              

            </tbody>
        </table>




        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Me gustaria saber como hacer para llamar a un controlador que genere dichas directamente los objetos que cree.
Y tambien si solamente utilizando los valores de asp-for sobre los elementos ya me hace las validaciones de los modelos directamente.

Comment: Podrías explicar mejor lo que quieres hacer, para poder ayudarte.